# how to create pattern for not allow some word set?

Tags: regex

I can allow some word set by pattern.

example:

```
^(polo shirt|tshirt)$
```

[live](https://regex101.com/r/sS3jS5/1)

but I want to disallow some word by pattern.

Comment: What do you want to disallow? Could you post some examples for valid and invalid matches?

Comment: @Avinash Raj  i want all another word without polo shirt & tshirt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex if you don't want to allow the word `shirt`

```
^(?!.*\b(?:polo shirt|tshirt)\b).*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sS3jS5/4)

`(?!.*\b(?:polo shirt|tshirt)\b)` negative lookahead at the start asserts that the string we are going to match won't contain the substring `tshirt` or `polo shirt`.

**OR**

Use anchors ,

```
^(?!^(?:polo shirt|tshirt|other)$)\w+(?:\s+\w+)*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sS3jS5/8)

**OR**

Simply use the pcre verb `(*SKIP)(*F)`

```
    ^(?:polo shirt|tshirt)$(*SKIP)(*F)|^.+

    |<-strings you don't want ------->|<-strings you want
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sS3jS5/5)

This skips the lines which contain only the words `polo shirt` or `tshirt` and matches all the other lines.

Comment: some working. but, can i add more word set like `polo shirt|tshirt|raglan|more word`

Comment: i use `^(?!.*\b(?:polo shirt|tshirt|other)).*$` but not match `others`. i want match `others` but not match `other` [live](https://regex101.com/r/sS3jS5/6)

Comment: add a word boundary at the last inside negative lookahead . see https://regex101.com/r/sS3jS5/7

Comment: i think, now it will work properly. thanks. but more thane one word matching. ex: i want to match "other word" not ("other" or  "other ")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67197/discussion-between-ahosan-karim-asik-and-avinash-raj).

Comment: please update your code with `^(?!^(?:polo shirt|tshirt|other)$)(\w+|\w+\s+\w+)+$` . i have wanted this like `<input name="cost_style_no"  pattern="^(?!^(?:polo shirt|tshirt|other)$)(\w+|\w+\s+\w+)+$"  value=""  required   type="text"  />`.